# SharpDX drawing a form without using RenderLoop to actualize it infinitely

Tags: c#, sharpdx

Hi so like the title says, i'm trying to make an image Viewer for a project ( a bit in the kind of Windows Image viewer). I saw a lot of code displaying their RenderForm into a RenderLoop, but I don't like this solution since I don't want to refresh the image infinitely in the RenderLoop. I want to call the Draw method only when I need to redraw(on a zoom by example.)  The problem is, now I've tried to use renderLoop.Show() but it does not stay on the screen and close right after all code has been executed...

```
using SharpDX;
using SharpDX.Windows;
using SharpDX.D3DCompiler;
using SharpDX.Direct2D1;
using SharpDX.Direct3D11;
using SharpDX.DXGI;
using SharpDX.Mathematics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using Device = SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device;
using Color = SharpDX.Color;



namespace SharpDXWic
{
    public class SharpDXDisplay : IDisposable
    {

        private const int WIDTH = 1500;
        private const int HEIGHT = 800;

        private Device device;
        private SwapChain swapChain;
        private RenderForm renderForm;
        private RenderTargetView targetView;

        public SharpDXDisplay(string display_title)
        {



            renderForm = new RenderForm(display_title);
            renderForm.Width = WIDTH;
            renderForm.Height = HEIGHT;

            Texture2D target;


            SwapChainDescription scd = new SwapChainDescription()
            {
                BufferCount = 1,                                
                Flags = SwapChainFlags.None,
                IsWindowed = true,                              
                ModeDescription = new ModeDescription(WIDTH,HEIGHT, new Rational(60, 1),Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm),                   
                OutputHandle = renderForm.Handle,  
                SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0), 
                SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard,
                Usage = Usage.RenderTargetOutput
            };
            Device.CreateWithSwapChain( SharpDX.Direct3D.DriverType.Hardware,DeviceCreationFlags.Debug,  scd,   out device, out swapChain);

            target = Texture2D.FromSwapChain<Texture2D>(swapChain, 0);
            targetView = new RenderTargetView(device, target);
            device.ImmediateContext.OutputMerger.SetRenderTargets(targetView);

            renderForm.Show();
            device.ImmediateContext.ClearRenderTargetView(targetView, Color.CornflowerBlue);
            swapChain.Present(0, PresentFlags.None);

        }

        private void OnClosing()
        {
            Dispose();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            device.Dispose();
            swapChain.Dispose();
            renderForm.Dispose();
            targetView.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

My goal here would be to Draw() a form without entering the RenderLoop.  I only want to refresh the image on-demand and not refresh it constantly.

Comment: All windows are driven by a loop. Games are constantly drawing everything every frame. The trick is leave actual calculations out of the render code.

Comment: Do you have any idea if it is possible to have a viewer that draws only on demand. By using Window form maybe ? The thing is that the Graphics . DrawImage is too slow for the size of image I need to display and this is why I turned on sharpDX.

Comment: It shouldn't be too slow unless you are recreating the image every draw. Draw everything that's static at once, cache it, and only render the cached image each frame. Anything dynamic, overlay on top of it. If you are creating a new image/texture every frame, you're doing it wrong. With games, you only update what has to be updated and there are lots of tricks employed to optimize that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in fact possible to display an image into a Windows Form without using an infinite loop. Adding action like zooming or resizing to your form and perform action (such has redraw your image) works perfectly.

Of course, if you are making a video game, that is not the best solution because you want constant render of your graphics. However, for an image viewer, it is perfectly fine to draw everything to a windows form only once and update it on ActionEvents.